# Inject string values using JavaScript without RegEx?

Tags: javascript

What is the easiest / most concise way to inject values into a string without using a RegEx expression or complex function?

For example, this:

```
var a = 'cats';
var b = 'dogs';

var result = String.format('%a and %b living together', a, b);
console.log(result);
```

... should yield ...

```
cats and dogs living together
```

I'm coming from the C# world where this is ridiculously easy.  Every search on SO turns up some type of overcomplicated RegEx expression or replace function.

Answer (score 3):

[Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) is probably the most concise (require ES6).

```
var result = `${a} and ${b} living together`;
```

On the other hand, regular string concatenation isn't that bad either.

```
var result = '' + a + ' and ' + b + ' living together';
```

Comment: Wonderful, I just discover here that JS have kind of _here-doc_, thanks

Comment: Need ES>=6 :/ ...

Comment: @GillesQuenot most modern browsers support it. https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-template_literals

Comment: Yes, but I work everyday with CasperJS